# StackAuth needs crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml

Tags: bug, status-completed

These would be helpful to have. Absence breaks Silverlight apps.

- http://stackauth.com/crossdomain.xml
- http://stackauth.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml
- http://stackauth.com/0.8/crossdomain.xml
- http://stackauth.com/0.8/clientaccesspolicy.xml

Comment: @Geoff - danke schoen.